# Domain URL or Address Using VPN Server

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, vpn

I  Have Created the VPN Client Application Using the open VPN Servers "VPN Gate", Now I want to block some IP addresses and websites that do not open when VPN is Connected can I manage this at the application end "Java" or Kotlin any Solution?

Packet Capturing , Traffic Details

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For Example When i Connect through Vpn i want to Block  Website "https://www.google.com" remaining all websites will open except this one